# How can I know if a character will fit into the grid, and if it won't, how many spaces it needs?

Tags: unicode, ncurses

With ncurses, how can I know whether or not a certain character will fit into the grid? I assume that this is font-dependent and am not sure at all how to do it.

[image: example text rendered in terminal emulator]

So in the above example, the function I am looking for would:

```
grid_spaces_per_char(L"字") => 2
grid_spaces_per_char(L"G") => 1
grid_spaces_per_char(L"") => 2
grid_spaces_per_char(L"Q") => 1
grid_spaces_per_char(L"。") => 2
```

I need to know this so that I can implement word wrapping in a UTF-8 aware C++ Slack ncurses application.

If it cannot be done with ncurses alone, what should I do instead to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wcwidth` is only part of the solution: ncurses expands control characters (other than whitespace) into two characters.  The "easy" way to do this is to write the character onto a window which is not displayed, and use the position before/after to find the actual width which ncurses would use on the visible ([`refresh`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-refresh_wrefresh)ed) windows.  A window can be created, used for a workspace and deleted without affecting what is shown on the screen.

That technique is used in [Lynx](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/view.c#L308),

```
    /*
     * Determine the number of cells the given string would take up on the screen,
     * limited (in the case of wide characters) by the maxCells parameter.
     *
     * If the returnCellNum parameter is TRUE, return the number of cells;
     * otherwise, return the length (limited by the len parameter) of the prefix of
     * the string that fits in maxCells cells.
     */
```

as well as the ncurses-examples program [`view`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/view.c#L308), which comments

```
    /*
     * Use the curses library for rendering, including tab-conversion.  This
     * will not make the resulting array's indices correspond to column for
     * lines containing double-width cells because the "in_wch" functions will
     * ignore the skipped cells.  Use pads for that sort of thing.
     */
```

By the way:

- `wcwidth`gives different results on different systems, and it may not actually correspond to what is shown on the terminal.  That is a limitation due to the way standards are introduced, and rather than building one on top of another, there are conflicting interpretations, incomplete documentation, etc.
- It should also be (but apparently is rarely) locale-dependent since some characters have different widths in different locales.  In `xterm`, both issues come to play with [line-drawing](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/util.c#L4803)

```
    /*
     * Solaris 10 wcwidth() returns "2" for all of the line-drawing (page
     * 0x2500) and most of the geometric shapes (a few are excluded, just
     * to make it more difficult to use).  Do a sanity check to avoid using
     * it.
     */
```

and [soft-hyphens](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/charproc.c#L5054)

```
        /*
         * Regarding the soft-hyphen aberration, see
         * http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/09/02/736881.html
         */
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question :) You are a real legend when it comes to console applications! You've been doing this longer than I've been alive, so thanks a lot for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself by using some different keywords -- the answer is to use `wcswidth` or `wcwidth` found in `wchar.h`.

There are some caveats, for example, Windows does not include this function, and it can sometimes be out of date. More caveats explained [here](http://denisbider.blogspot.com/2015/09/when-monospace-fonts-arent-unicode.html) and [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10206380).